# boost signals2 connecting using XML file

Tags: c++, xml, boost, signals, slots

in the following code example I would like to define the connections between the outputSignal and the slots in a XML file and I would like then to connect the actual objects according to that XML. How can I do that?

```
class A
{
public:
    boost::signals2<void (bool)> outputSignal;
    void slotReceiveInt(int i)
    {
    };
};

class B
{
public:
    boost::signals2<void (int)> outputSignal;
    void slotReceiveBool(bool b)
    {
    };
};

class C
{
public:
    boost::signals2<void (bool)> outputSignal;
    void slotReceiveInt(int i)
    {
    };
}

A a;
B b;
C c;
```